# PhalconPHP - registerPrefixes in loader

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to split my lib folder into a few folders. I thought that prefixes in autoloader should be the most balanced method between code writing and performance. The problem is that I need to rename every file and every class name inside to match the name with prefix included.

Before:

```
-app
----lib
-------Class1.php
-------Class2.php
-------Class3.php
```

After how it must be to work:

```
-app
----lib
--------general
-----------General_Class1.php
-----------General_Class2.php
--------app
-----------App_Class3.php
```

After how I want it to be:

```
-app
----lib
--------general
-----------Class1.php
-----------Class2.php
--------app
-----------Class3.php
```

Right now to register those prefixes I'm using the following code:

```
// Register some prefixes
$loader->registerPrefixes(
    array(
        "App_"    => $config->application->libraryDir . "app/",
        "General_"    => $config->application->libraryDir . "general/",
    )
);

$loader->register();

$server = new App_Class3();
echo $server->testMethod('test');
```

It it possible to call certain classes with for example App_Class3 but without renaming the file and the class name inside (using prefixes method or similar)?

Comment: Could you not use namespaces?

Comment: I could... And I did. But the problem still remains because somebody maybe won't want to use namespaces instead of prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phalcon's loader can do this. It is explained in [Phalcon's docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html#registering-prefixes).

You just register prefixes in the loader like you would namespaces.

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;

// Creates the autoloader
$loader = new Loader();

// Register some prefixes
$loader->registerPrefixes(
    array(
        "Example_Base"    => "vendor/example/base/",
        "Example_Adapter" => "vendor/example/adapter/"
    ));
```